# How To Total array column?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have data

A = 100
I wanna output like this

> qty  | qty_sisa

```
10    A-10 = 90
20    90-20 = 70
30    70-30 = 40
40    40-40 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
foreach (array_keys($a - $b) as $key) {
    $c[$key] = $a[$key] - $b[$key];
}
```